# Preferred ways to define array in perl

Tags: perl

Is the any difference in the following ways to define array in perl?

Which is the preferred way? Thanks

A

```
my @eles = (
    "abc",
    "bbc"
);
```

B

```
@eles = ("abc", "bbc");
```

C

```
@eles = qw(abc, bbc);
```

D

```
@eles = qw(
abc
bbc
);
```

E

```
@eles = qw{
abc
bbc
};
```

F

```
@eles = qw(abc bbc);
```

Comment: Minus the typo (?) it's preference. And if there is one thing perl is pretty opinionated about, it is about not having an..

Comment: A and B are identical except for whitespace, C is wrong (almost certainly not what you intended), and D, E, and F are identical except for whitespace or syntactical sugar. So the question is really: A or D? And the answer is: if none of your elements contain spaces, D is perfectly fine, otherwise A.

Comment: C is syntactically valid, so not "wrong" in that sense, but, because it's almost certainly not what is intended, Perl will warn of "Possible attempt to separate words with commas" if warnings are enabled. And warnings _are_ enabled, aren't they? (If not, they almost certainly should be!)

Comment: My force of habit was using `push` or `cat $file`, the real thihg is a similar bug like C in mac `foreach my $ele qw(a,b)` , took a while to figure out.

Comment: `qw` has the downside that it doesn't allow comments (unless you use `use syntax qw( qw_comments );`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are all the same except for example C which produces an array with element 0 equal to `abc,` (note the comma).  I use `qw()` when it makes the code more readable, which is most of the time if you are defining a large array with "configuration" data.

Comment: But don't forget the `my` because none of the above have them (and you really should be using `strict`).